# Is this equation separable, if so find the general solution?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I need to find if this equation is seperable, and if it is find the general solution.
 So far ive got.

$\frac{dy}{dx} -xy^2 = 2xy +x^2$

${dy} -xy^2 = 2xy +x^2 dx$

$dy = 2xy +x^2 +xy^2 dx$

$\frac{dy}{y^2} = 2xy +x^2 +x dx$

$\frac{dy}{y^2}/{y} = 2x+x^2 +x dx$

$\frac{dy}{y} = 2x+x^2 +x dx$

Is this separated and if so how would i find the general solution.

Comment: It's not seperable... it's a first order nonlinear ordinary differential equation

Comment: I dont think there is a closed form solution in terms of common functions either, in case you were wondering

Answer (score 1):

The first step was wrong, you just... did not apply basic algebra in correct way. When "multiplying $dx$", each term gets a $dx$.

Rearrange terms as you would do for solving equations:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=xy^2+2xy+x^2$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=x(y^2+2y+x)$$

Observe that it is not separable.